# Missing value for primary key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am upgrading from doctrine 2.3 to 2.5 and some of the relationships have broken.

I had a look other stack overflow questions. But there is only one id annotation is these classes and the join columns are named after their db column names, not their variable name on the entity

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="iso_country_shipping_display")
 */
class IsoCountryShippingDisplay {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(name="iso_country_shipping_display_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="namespace\Website")
     * @JoinColumn(name="website_id", referencedColumnName="base_website_id", nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @var Website
     */
    private $baseWebsite;

    /**
     * @var IsoCountry
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="namespace\IsoCountry")
     * @JoinColumn(name="iso_3", referencedColumnName="iso_3", nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $isoCountry;

    /**
     * @return IsoCountry
     */
    public function getIsoCountry()
    {
        return $this->isoCountry;
    }
}
```

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="iso_country")
 */
class Website
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="website_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @var integer
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

I got the error message `Missing value for primary key id on namespace\Website`. I am not sure why I am getting this on doctrine 2.5 but not on 2.3.

Comment: @GeneratedValue seems to be missing on Website, So, the Id is null when recording.

Comment: Normally I would suggest dropping the leading backslash from your targetEntity="\namespace\Website" annotations.  But I suspect they are only there because of copy/paste issues when writing your question.  Same reason your Website class is mapped to the iso_country table.  I get the desire to simplify your posted code but it is difficult to review when there are some many errors.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant I have added `@ GeneratedValue `, but I am still getting the same issue

Comment: @Cerad I removed the backslash, I thought that would work but, i am still getting the same error message

Comment: Check your existing database and verify that all of your tables actually have values for their primary ids and (when applicable) values for their foreign keys.  Are you getting the error when loading an existing entity or when creating a new one?  By the way, you still have plenty of copy/paste errors in your question.  Fixing them up might help.

Comment: Are IsoCountry and Website entities both referencing `iso_country` table?

Answer (score -1):

Add `* @GeneratedValue` value annotation to the `Website` Entity.

Comment: I have added `@GeneratedValue`, but I am still getting the same issue